# problemas de compatibilidad con mi aplicación android

Tags: android-studio

Hola tengo una aplicación que programé con la última versión de android-studio. Es la aplicación de una radio. Está programado en web view. El problema es que probé la app en android 6.0.1, y me funciona normal, pero no funciona en android 9.0. Cuando le doy al botón de reproducir en teoría sí reproduce, por que el botón cambia a pausar, pero no se escucha el audio. Me pueden ayudar? gracias. Les dejo mi código.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.rme.radiorme;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    WebView wv1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv1);

        WebSettings ajustes = wv1.getSettings();
        ajustes.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/radio rme.html");
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rme.radiorme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: has comprobado la compatibilidad?

Comment: Importante revisar el LogCat, cuál es el mensaje que se muestra ? Que tiene dentro radio rme.html? Saludos